# Running a Command With Another User's PATH Variable

Tags: permissions, sudo, path, su

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

The problem I have is with running commands as another user (sudo/runuser/...). I'm unable to find a set of options for any of them that run the command with the target user's $PATH settings. I first saw the issue running rake commands via Ansible but I've boiled it down to some simple command line tests with a user named 'deploy'.

When running commands as user ubuntu:

```
ubuntu@dev:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Same command as the user deploy:

```
deploy@dev:/home/ubuntu$ echo $PATH
/home/deploy/.yarn/bin:/home/deploy/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
#(This is the desired PATH value)
```

Attempting to use sudo to run the command as the user deploy:

```
ubuntu@dev:~$ sudo su deploy -c "echo $PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
#(Wrong $PATH value, it's the path for user ubuntu again)
```

```
ubuntu@dev:~$ sudo -u deploy --login echo $PATH

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
(Wrong $PATH value, it's the path for user ubuntu again)
```

Attempting to use runuser to run the command as the user deploy:

```
ubuntu@dev:~$ sudo runuser -l deploy -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
#(Wrong $PATH value, not sure which but it's not the PATH of deploy)
```

The command "echo $PATH" is just a stand-in for the rake commands I'm trying to run. I've tried many other combinations. They all fail, mostly returning the path of the session running the command. Does anyone know a combination of command and options that would run a command as though the specified user had started a shell and had their user specific PATH values?

Thanks
.

Comment: `sudo su deploy -c "echo $PATH"` Your shell replaces $PATH with the value it has in its environment before launching `sudo`. Same for the other examples.

Comment: `sudo -u root sh -c 'echo $HOME'` work in my shell. It print `/root`

Answer (score 2):

The comment by @berndbausch is correct that you need single quotes, not double quotes.  You may benefit also from using the `-l` option for `su(1)` to simulate a full login:

```
# sudo su -l deploy -c 'echo $PATH'
```

Answer (score 0):

When I try it:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/bbausch/bin:/home/bbausch/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
$ sudo sh -c "echo $PATH"
/home/bbausch/bin:/home/bbausch/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
$ sudo sh -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

Note the single quotes. This is so because the shell performs variable expansion in double-quoted strings before calling the command. However, how environment variables are treated can be configured in the `sudoers` file.

Comment: Thanks @berndbausch.  The quote style I was using was definitely having an effect on the test I was using to sort this out. I'm still seeing a difference in the results though with the single quotes. I'll go back and try just running the real commands to see if I'm just missing something.